# value error with datetime.strptime

Tags: python

I am trying to read dates from a txt file and have that converted to datetime format

**Code**:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

with open("birth.txt") as f:
   content = f.readlines()
   content = [x.strip() for x in content] 
   for i in content:
     a = i.split(":")
     date_b = []
     date_b.append(a[-1])
     print date_b
     for j in date_b:
        date_object = datetime.strptime(str(j), '%m-%d-%Y')
        print date_object
```

**Text File**:

```
a:11-23-2001
b:02-14-2002
```

> ValueError: time data ' 11-23-2001' does not match format '%m-%d-%Y'

Can someone help me resolve this error?

Comment: Your dates have a leading space, do `j.strip()`

Comment: Try printing `j` before it's passed to `strptime`

Comment: Your code with that text doesn't raise any errors for me

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problematic parts with your code. The error is caused by having a space before your date string although I'm not sure where it comes from given your file. Also, why are you even having the second loop? And you're overwriting the `date_b` in each line loop... Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

with open("birth.txt") as f:
    dates = []  # store this outside of your loop
    for line in f:  # read line by line
        v, d = line.strip().split(":")
        d = datetime.strptime(d.strip(), '%m-%d-%Y')  # just in case of additional whitespace
        dates.append((v, d))
print(dates)
# [('a', datetime.datetime(2001, 11, 23, 0, 0)), ('b', datetime.datetime(2002, 2, 14, 0, 0))]
```

You can turn the latter into a dictionary, too (`dict(dates)`) or build a dictionary immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the issues that @zwer points out, you have the major inefficiency of reading the entire file into memory before processing it. This actually makes your job harder than it needs to be because files in Python are iterable over their lines. You can do something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

with open('birth.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        key, datestr = line.strip().split(':')
        dateobj = datetime.strptime(datestr, '%m-%d-%Y')
        print(dateobj)
```

Using the fact that the file is an iterator, you can write a one-line list comprehension to generate a full list of dates:

```
with open('birth.txt') as f:
    dates = [datetime.strptime(line.strip().split(':')[1], '%m-%d-%Y') for line in f]
```

If the key has some significance, you can create a dictionary with a dictionary comprehension using a similar syntax:

```
with open('birth.txt') as f:
    dates = {key: datetime.strptime(datestr, '%m-%d-%Y') for key, datestr in (line.strip().split(':') for line in f)}
```